# How to send a function that has string to a remote instance in kdb?

Tags: kdb

I already opened up the handle. I am trying to change the function in remote instance. Below is my code

```
h "loadHDB:{value "\\l /mnt/data/ord_us"}"
```

but it didn't work. I tried to add \ \ in string too but didn't work.

Comment: i tried this and this also didn't work h "\l  /mnt/data/ord_us". anyone knows the correct way?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to use `set` to redefine `loadHDB` in the remote process. And using `system` means you can avoid escaping the backslash:

```
q)h ("set";`loadHDB; {value system "l /mnt/data/ord_us"})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape out your internal quotation marks, as follows:

```
q)h "loadHDB:{value \"\\l /mnt/data/ord_us\"}"
```

I don't know is the loading will work, but at least the string should be correct.

Comment: it seems the syntax is right, but there is error for the for \l /mnt/data/ord_us after i ran it

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use -3! (.Q.s1) to 'double string' it. Remember that -3! is dependent on console size, so this approach may not always be appropriate. For these remote functions, the idea is to enclose the code to be executed inside double quotes - any other strings within this must be -3!'ed and joined on. A useful 'test' is to -1 print the message. The result should look like what you would execute on the remote console.

E.g.

```
q)printmsg:{-1 x;show value x;}
q)printmsg "2+2"
2+2
4
q)printmsg "system ",-3!"echo ",string .z.h
system "echo illysemacbook.local"
"illysemacbook.local"
q)-1 " "sv("John said";-3!"Hello Sir!";"Frank said";-3!"something!")
John said "Hello Sir!" Frank said "something!"
```

Is that useful?